# TeXLive/PDFTeX fonts loading problem

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive

I'm using TexLive on Windows

Please look at my error log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (Web2C 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./APSBezierSegment_out.tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, uk
english, usenglishmax, loaded.
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/pxfonts.sty)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ucs.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode/data/uni-global.def))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/koi8-r.def)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8x.def))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/p2e-pdftex.def)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t2aenc.def)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t2acmr.fd)
! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.
 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

? 
! Emergency stop.
 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on APSBezierSegment_out.log.
```

And here is mine input file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color,pxfonts,fix-cm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[koi8-r,utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\qbezier(200,0)(150,150)(400,0)
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

What is the problem here. And how that can be solved?

Comment: Why are you loading the `koi8-r` and `T2A` encodings?

Comment: @egreg Well this is pattern-like file with common header for some bunch of other files, so I need it here.

Comment: Loading T2A forces LaTeX to look for cyrillic fonts; I'm quite surprised that it works with other files and not this one.

Comment: @egreg Actually it doesn't work with other files. I gave input file just for example. The same situation is processed correctly on *nix. Why the problem persists on Windows?

Comment: The problem are surely missing packages for cyrillic support; look for them with `tlmgr`. However, that preamble is *wrong* when your default language is English: T1 should go last.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The font `larm1000` is the base font for the cyrillic encoding `T2A` that you are choosing to be the default for your document, as it is the last appearing in

```
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
```

This should be corrected, if the default language is English, as specified by

```
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
```

In order to avoid the problem, install with `tlmgr` all the packages in `collection-langcyrillic`, in particular the `lh` package.